# Getting error when call "createClient" function from Redis in Reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redis

Can anyone solve this matter? I had a bug when trying to import createClient from Redis in my Reactjs project.

[image]

My Reactjs code:

```
const { createClient } from "redis";
const redisClient = createClient({ url: "redis://localhost:6379" });
```

Versions:
node: 16.5.0; npm: 8.5.4; react: 17.0.2; redis: 4.2.0

Answer (score 1):

node-redis is not intented to run in the browser